# Underscore JS to retrieve object by ID

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I have a input where I want to find an object by ID. At the moment I am returning both objects but what I want is if I search '01' I would just return the first object. I have tried underscore _.map to do this but it did not give the result I am after.

```
var getById = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer(),
        result;

    result = items;

    if (!result) {
        deferred.reject('item not found');
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(result);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

JSON:

```
[{
  "id": "01",
  "name": "test1",
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "productNumber": "TESTa",
      "quantity": 2,
    },
    {
      "productNumber": "TESTb",
      "quantity": 4,
    },
    {
      "productNumber": "TESTc",
      "quantity": 6,
    }
  ]
},{
  "id": "02",
  "name": "test2",
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "productNumber": "TESTe",
      "quantity": 2,
    },
    {
      "productNumber": "TESTf",
      "quantity": 7,
    },
    {
      "productNumber": "TESTg",
      "quantity": 6,
    }
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.filter()`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)

> Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that pass a truth test (predicate).

```
result = _.filter(items, function(item){
    return item.id == '01';
});
```

Or, [_.findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere)

> Looks through the list and returns the first value that matches all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.

```
result  = _.findWhere(items, {id : '01'});
```

Comment: That is really helpful, how would I do it so I don't hard code '01' but rather depending on which one I input would give me the correct result?

Comment: @Pianoc, You can replace `01` with a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = _.find(myItems, function(item) { return item.id === '01'; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find single item which matches the conditions, use **_.find()**

> It looks through each value in the list, returning the first one that
>   passes a truth test

```
         var _exist = _.find(_items, function (item) {
             return item.id == your_id;
            });
```

If you find all items which matches the conditions, use **_.filter()**

> It looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the
>   values that pass a truth test

```
var _exist = _.filter(_items, function (item) {
                 return item.id == your_id;
                });
```

Catch the complete documentation here:
http://underscorejs.org/